# Building ggplot using geom_bar vs stat_identity

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Why does this

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_bar(aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length),stat="identity")
```

[image]

and this

```
ggplot(iris) + stat_identity(aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length),geom="bar")
```

[image]

have different y-axis? I was just testing if they were equivalent in usage.

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
ggplot2_2.2.1
```

Comment: The default `position` differs: `geom_bar`: `"stack"` vs `stat_identity`: `"identity"`. Thus, the bar heights are `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, sum)` vs `tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, max)`

Answer (score 0):

These two are working differently when you are plotting. From `ggplot2` documentation:

`geom_bar` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group, while `stat_identity` leaves the data unchanged. That is why you have two different scales.

See here for `geom_bar` http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

and here for `stat_identity`
http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_identity.html